# How to handle layout changes when clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have extended the Android `ListView` component to be able to make changes to its list items when they are clicked and to make the first item selected per default.

The problem is that when making changes to the list items by adding an `OnItemClickListener`, this event is not fired when an Activity overrides it. How can this behavior be set to always happen no matter if the event is overridden or not?

In relation to the above, I would also like that these changes are added to the first item in the list when initialized (as a default selection). I have been looking everywhere for a solution. Some of the things I have tried includes experimenting with `setSelection(0)`, `setSelected(true)`, `setActivated(true)` and `setItemChecked(0, true)`. I have also been trying to use `performClick()`, but this trows `NullPointerException`.
To indicate a click I'm using a `StateListDrawable` added as `android:background` to the list item.

**StateListDrawable:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_active" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_active" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_background"/>
</selector>
```

It should also be noted that I'm using a custom adapter for the listview, even though it is not doing anything else than adding contents to the list item.

**A short excerpt of the custom listview code:**

```
public class ShadowListview extends ListView {

    public ShadowListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    ...

    private void init() {
        setOnItemClickListener(new ShadowListViewClicker());
    }

    private class ShadowListViewClicker implements OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Handling changes to items here
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Any help to my issues are greatly appreciated, since I'm starting to loose my hair working on this :)

Comment: I did what @darnmason suggested and implemented an interface in the containing activity to support fragment callbacks on click events. No need to extend ListView - the adapter does the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle it all in the adapter, maintain an integer representing the selected index, defaulted to 0. Modify your `getView` to render the view differently if the index matches the selected index. Provide a public `setSelected(int)` method in the adapter that will update the selected index and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list. In your `onItemClick` method call `setSelected` on the adapter.

Comment: Your suggestion is similar to how I handle the changes already in the event, but I didn't think of handling everything in the adapter. But what if I want the described behavior of the list regarding of the adapter it is using? Then this wouldn't work?

Comment: Well if it's something as generic as setting an item as selected on click then maybe you could get the view of the item in `onItemClick` and call `setSelected` on it, while setting every other item as notSelected. This could be done using a combination of ListView's `getFirstVisiblePosition` and `getChildAt` methods. I'm surprised that `setSelection` and `getSelectedItem` don't already handle this?